# How to deploy a Python selenium script on a server where I can send the input via API and it returns the output via API?

Tags: python, api, selenium, selenium-webdriver, server

I have a python selenium script that takes an input URL, scrapes a specific website, and generates an output. I want to deploy that selenium script on a server so that I can use an API to send input, and the script will use that input to scrape the website and return the output via API. I am building a web app where users can come and give their input, and the script will scrape the data and return the output to users.

I have used the script on Heroku and several VPSs but haven't figured out how to call the script via API and then return the data. I need to deploy it on a server so I can use the script whenever I want by sending the input, and the input will start the scraper, scrape the data, and returns the output. Following is the generalized form of script I am looking to be deployed:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# this function is used to setup the bot
def bot_setup(headless=False):
    # options to be used
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    if headless:
        options.add_argument("--headless")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
        options=options,
    )
    # setup implicit wait
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    return driver
    
def scrape(url):
    driver = bot_setup()
    driver.get(url)
    results = {}
    # all the scraping logic
    return results # need to return these results via API to frontend or to a database

url = "https://example.com"
scrape(url) # I want this url to come from an API
```

Comment: one way is: have a flask app and build an API in it, that API will use your code and can return the result. then deploy that flask app to server.Note: some free hosting blocks the access to external URL, for example, pythonanywhere does not let program access external urls.